# Lyx, MiKTeX, yfonts

Tags: lyx, miktex

I have `\usepackage{yfonts,color}` in my LyX preamble. The chapter begins with

```
(inserted tex code) \yinipar{\color{darkgray}B}
```

When I try to get a PDF output I get this error:

```
Font U/yinitas/m/n/10=yinitas not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I have LyX (v. 2.1) installed in two computers. In one of the everything works fine; the other gives the above error.

I have uninstalled and re-installed yfonts package a few times, reconfigured LyX, updated MiKTeX, none helped. Any ideas?

Comment: the tfm is in the gothic package, not in the yfonts package.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. (I don't remember installing the gothic package to my other computer. Weird.)